# login authentication in java Rest API getting Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, restful-authentication

In this example I'm trying to take parameters sent by android user at the time of login to authenticate user and in response I'm giving token but while checking it on postman I'm getting Unsupported Media Type Error

**Below is ApplicationConfig.java class**

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}

/**
 * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
 * It is automatically populated with
 * all resources defined in the project.
 * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
 */
private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
     resources.add(com.test.AuthenticationEndpoint.class);
}

}
```

**Below is AuthenticationEndpoint.java class**

```
 package com.test;

 import java.security.SecureRandom;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
 import javax.ws.rs.POST;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

 @Path("/authentication")
 public class AuthenticationEndpoint {
 String token=null;
@POST
@Path("/getData")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response authenticateUser(@FormParam("username") String username, 
                                 @FormParam("password") String password) {

    try {

        // Authenticate the user using the credentials provided
        authenticate(username, password);

        // Issue a token for the user
       // String token = issueToken(username);

        // Return the token on the response
        return Response.ok(token).build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }      
}

private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // Authenticate against a database, LDAP, file or whatever
    // Throw an Exception if the credentials are invalid
     boolean status = false;
    credentials cred=new credentials();
    String user = cred.getUsername();
    String pass = cred.getPassword();       

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

  try {
  String sql="Select userid,password,area,designation from login";
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename","root","");


  Statement st = con.createStatement();

        pst = conn
                .prepareStatement("select * from login where userid=? and password=?");
        pst.setString(1, user);
        pst.setString(2, pass);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        status = rs.next();

        if(status){
          token = issueToken(user);
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (pst != null) {
            try {
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}


}

private String issueToken(String username) {
    // Issue a token (can be a random String persisted to a database or a JWT token)
    // The issued token must be associated to a user
    // Return the issued token
   String user = username;
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    String token = bytes.toString();


     Connection conn;
     Statement st;
     ResultSet rs=null;
     try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     conn=DriverManager.

     getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basename","root","");

 st = conn.createStatement();
 String TableSQL = "UPDATE login SET token = ? WHERE userid = ?";
 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(TableSQL);
 preparedStatement.setString(1, token);
 preparedStatement.setString(2, user);
  // execute insert SQL stetement
 preparedStatement .executeUpdate();

}catch(Exception e){

}
 return token;
   }
   }
```

**Below credentials.java class**

```
package com.test;

public class credentials {

private String username;
private String password;
private String area;
private String designation;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getArea() {
    return area;
}

public void setArea(String area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}

}
```

Comment: `@PathParam` suggests that those variables are part of the URL, how are you calling your service with Postman ?

Comment: Sorry! I mistakenly added PathParam, Actually there is FormParam

Answer (score 0):

> @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)

As your endpoint is consuming APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, make sure to select correct media type in Postman as below

[image: x-www-form-urlencoded option selected in Postman]